# DHCP not working for bridged QEMU virtual machine

Tags: dhcp, bridge, qemu, bridge-router

Environment:

- A router with DHCP server. This router manages a subnet of 172.16.0.1/16
- A host with Ubuntu 20.04 installed, and it has a NIC named eno0.
- A QEMU virtual machine running on host.

Purpose:

Bridge the virtual machine with host's NIC to obtain IP via DHCP protocol.

What I have tried:

- Setup a bridge on host, and add the `eno0` interface in it:

  ```
  ip link add name br0 type bridge
  ip link set br0 up
  ip link set eno0 master br0
  ```
- Assign IP to `br0` via DHCP:

  ```
  dhclient br0
  ```
- Run qemu machine with tap network:

  ```
  qemu-system-x86_64 \
       -enable-kvm \
       -nographic \
       -drive format=raw,file=/path/to/img \
       -netdev tap,id=nic0,br=br0,helper=/opt/qemu/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper \
       -device e1000e,mac=52:54:00:12:34:50,netdev=nic0
  ```
- After virtual machine booting, try to obtain IP via `udhcpc` command (a dhclient variant in busybox):

  ```
  udpchc eth0
  ```

Till now, the eth0 cannot be assigned a IP in subnet 172.16.x.x/16.

So, is there anything wrong with my configuration?

---

**Update:**

To simplify this experiment, I use a dummy interface, say dm0, instead of eno0, and setup a DHCP server on that dm0 interface.

```
# Create a dummy interface
ip link add dm0 type dummy

# Create bridge and add dm0 to it
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set dm0 master br0

# Bring interfaces up
ip link set br0 up
ip link set dm0 up

# Setup a DHCP server on dm0, managed subnet is 10.0.0.1/24.
# Assign address to dm0 interface
ip addr add dev dm0 10.0.0.1/24

# Initiate QEMU virtual machine
qemu-system-x86_64 \
       -enable-kvm \
       -nographic \
       -drive format=raw,file=/path/to/img \
       -netdev tap,id=nic0,br=br0,helper=/opt/qemu/libexec/qemu-bridge-helper \
       -device e1000e,mac=52:54:00:12:34:50,netdev=nic0

# Try to obtain IP address in virtual machine
udhcpc -i eth0
```

Run tcpdump both on dm0 and tap0 interface by command:

```
tcpdump -nli dm0
tcpdump -nli tap0
```

I can see that the DHCP request is received by DHCP server, and the server gives responses by allocating a new IP address.

```
# From dm0 interface
17:44:50.237133 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:12:34:51, length 300
17:44:50.237239 IP 10.0.0.1.67 > 10.0.0.200.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

However, on interface tap0, only DHCP request packages can be seen. The response packages are missing.

```
17:44:50.237122 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 52:54:00:12:34:51, length 300
```

It seems that the response packages are filter out by bridge, which is the reason that VM cannot obtain a valid address, and I don't how to figure out what has happend.

Comment: 1. You'd expect VM address in `172.16.0.x/24`, not in `172.16.x.x/16`. I insist on a correct netmask! 2. After VM started, did you verify your tap interface was put into bridge? Did you try to check that bridge itself sees the traffic on tap port (with `bridge fdb show`, check for VM MAC)? (Also, btw, why are you are using `e1000e` and not `virtio-net-pci`?)

Comment: Usually , you need to bring down eno0 before making it a bridge "slave". Have you tried that.

Comment: Have you enabled IP forwarding on the host? If not, traffic that enters the host but is not destined to the host, e.g. DHCP responses for the VM, will be ignored. You could also trace traffic to see if anything comes out of the VM or the DHCP server: `tcpdump -neli NIC port 67 or port 68`, where you set NIC to the interfaces between the VM and the DHCP server.

Comment: OP seems to have no problem with `dhclient br0`, from which I conclude that the bridge's connection to the network is not at issue here.

Comment: @berndbausch: no, ip forwarding isn't needed for Ethernet bridging. It is only needed to actually *route* IPv4 packets.

Comment: This is simply wrong. You may run `ip link set eno0 up` and `ip link set eno0 master br0` in any order. There is no requirement to bring interface down (as in `ip link set eno0 down`) before setting its master.

Comment: On which interface has the *host* its address assigned to?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov the mask is a typo 1. The tap interface is exactly be bridged which can be verify by `bridge link`; 2. I don't know what `bridge fdb show` command do, but the MAC address of virtual machine exists in the output; 3. e1000e is only for testing, should this matter?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov For the first test, ip address is assigned to bridge br0 via `dhclient` tool.

Comment: In the ancient times there was a `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` setting, which calls iptables rules even for bridged packets. Do you have any firewall on the host?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` seems not exists on my host, and all rule is flushed by manually running `iptables -F`. I am not sure if that is enough to turn off iptables filter.

Comment: Not enough, you need to check if FORWARD policy is ACCEPT

Comment: also, do you see DISCOVER packet going out from `eno0`?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Actually, `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` causes this problem. But I don't know why another ubuntu 20.04 server doesn't have `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` entry at all. Thank you for your patient and kind help.

Comment: Did you solved a problem (by setting it to 0 or by adding proper firewall rules)? I may formulate that as an answer to help further readers.

Comment: Yes, the problem has gone. Basically, it is due to the `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` option, which need to be set to 0 to disable iptables filter on bridge device.

Comment: I had ~same issue and it got solved by disabling docker and containerd services + reboot more info here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594387/kvm-client-no-dhcp-with-host-bridge-when-docker-is-running

Comment: where did you set this?
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables also should probly mark or make a answer for future people

Answer (score 2):

I promised to formulate my comment which solved the problem in the form of an answer and forgot. Shame on me. Let me fix that already; @DouglasSu please accept for future readers to be aware of the solution.

The problem is that Netfilter (the Linux firewall) blocked forwarding of said packet. Why it blocked a *bridged* packet?

There is a knob in the kernel whether it calls the IP-level firewall for bridged packets. In ancient distros it was called `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables`, which controlled overall system behaviour (e.g. for all bridges simultaneously). In such old system you may add into `/etc/sysctl.d/bridge.conf`:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
```

And `iptables` rules won't get traversed for bridged packets.
To check a setting, you may run `sysctl | grep bridge-nf-call-iptables`.

In new systems, this is controllable per-bridge with `nf_call_iptables` variable (and its friends):

```
# ip link add type bridge help
...
                  [ nf_call_iptables NF_CALL_IPTABLES ]
                  [ nf_call_ip6tables NF_CALL_IP6TABLES ]
                  [ nf_call_arptables NF_CALL_ARPTABLES ]
...
```

E.g. you may set it for each bridge individually, for example, during creation:

```
# ip link add name br0 type bridge nf_call_iptables 0
```

and check value using `ip -d link show br0` or in `/sys/class/net/br0/bridge/nf_call_iptables`. There you can also change its value at runtime.

And, at last, you may properly configure `iptables` to allow bridged packets. There is `physdev` match to determine which bridge port the packet was entered from.

Comment: Well, I wanted to tune up my `dnsmasq.config` for ipv6 clients. I created 3xVM with `tap` networking. In the host system I connected all taps (tap1, tap2, tap3) to br1, configured with `ip link add name br1 type bridge nf_call_iptables 0 nf_call_ip6tables 0` . I configured the VM1 with `dnsmasq` to offer the IP and IPv6 on the MAC address request: `dhcp-host=mac,ipv4,ipv6,nameX.test.home,12h` . If I set IP4/6 to all VM manually, all VM communicate well. When VM1 is set manually, and I let VM2 and 3 ask for DHCP, I can see the DHCPREQUEST with wireshark, but no answer with DHCPOFFER . Any hint?

Comment: Excellent, thanks for writing up. The issue occurred in my case only on servers running Docker. What appears to cause the issue is that installing Docker changes the default for the `iptables FORWARD` chain from `ACCEPT` to `DROP`. The cleaner solution (apart from reporting a bug with the `docker.io` package) would then be to add an `ACCEPT` at the end of the chain.

Comment: Not at all. In case of Docker, you'd better move QEMU virtual machines away from Docker hosts. Docker is very neglecting of other network-related software and it is very intrusive into networking stack, so basically it is the best not to mix it with anything else on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
sudo sysctl -w "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Comment: Both commands in general have nothing to do with *bridging*, which is this question all about.